# nuget hell when using aspnetcore 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget

hi can somebody explain in english why Am I getting this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Version conflict detected for 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration. 
Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue. 
 MyProject.MyWebApi -> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly 2.1.1 
 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Http 2.1.1 
 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.1.1 
 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 2.1.1
 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 2.1.1) 
  MyProject.MyWebApi -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 
-> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (= 2.1.0).            0
```

I was trying to update a package via nuget in a solution where I have some projects that my api references

- Should nuget automatically work it out? Why is it getting confused?
- Is there a good practice/guideline to follow when using the same nuget in different projects in the same solution?

thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Yes that is the problem but when trying to update it seems to get confused how can I check what version of dotnetcoresdk I have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have updated some Microsoft packages to 2.1.1 in your .csproj but others you have as 2.1.0 which is a conflict. If you want to use 2.1.1 Microsoft libs you have to update all of them to 2.1.1, you can't leave some of them as 2.1.0

Also in order to use the 2.1.1 packages make sure you have installed the latest DotNet Core sdk version 2.1.301

Comment: To be more precise, you need to update all *referenced* project packages to 2.1.1. You can have different projects using different versions of ASP.NET Core packages, as long as they don't depend on each other.

Comment: @ChrisPratt unfortunately many dependent on each other updated to latest dotnetcore and worked

Comment: @developer9969: Sure. I just wanted it noted for posterity, since it wasn't clear that this is only an issue when projects have dependencies on each other.